# R data selection using sapply not working

Tags: r, csv

I have following code for getting the pollutant mean. The data for the program are in folder specdata with names "001.csv", "002.csv", ... to "332.csv" . The names of any one data gives following names:

```
[1] "Date"    "sulfate" "nitrate" "ID"
```

In the code below, I have to calculate the mean of pollutant nitrate or sulfate . I think the code is correct. But data$pollutant is giving

> NULL
>
> Error in pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 23) :    attempt to
>   apply non-function

The code is supposed to call in following way:

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 23)
```

What am I doing wrong here??

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
  f <- function(num){
    if(num>=0 & num<=9){
      fname <- paste('specdata/00',as.character(num),".csv",sep="")
    }
    else if (num>=10 & num <=99){
      fname <- paste('specdata/0',as.character(num),".csv",sep="")
    }
    else{
      fname <- paste('specdata/',as.character(num),".csv",sep="")
    }
    data <- read.csv(fname)
    data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
    return(mean(data$pollutant))
  }
  results <- sapply(id, f)
  return(results)

}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but useful hint: run `sprintf("%03.f", 1:322)`.

Comment: ah thanks! this could have saved me in looping above. I learning R. This is good and shortcut method. Thanks

Comment: Minor point: you also hard-code `"specdata/"` and never use `directory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have is most probably caused by calling `data$pollutant`. You have `pollutant="nitrate"`, which is a character string, in that case reference by `$` is not going to work. Use `[]` instead, here's a minimal example:

```
df <- data.frame(hello=1:3, world=5)
name <- "hello"
df$name
NULL
df[name]
#  hello
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. But check that df$"hello" still gives the data. So, I was getting the confusion.

Comment: Please tell me how df$"hello" gives the answer but df$name doesn't

Comment: `df$name` is interpreted as "search column names for something like 'name'", so there is no actual lookup for variable `name`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-specific-column-using-the-dollar-sign-in-r/18228613#18228613) answer for more details.